# Problem Populating array on Click Event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura

I'm getting some problems when populating an array of objects that I click.
I want to fill with objects I click on, but everytime that I click on a new object the old value get cleared and filled with the new one

**JS-AURA**

````
      
      var arrayList = component.get('v.listSave')
      var getSelectUser = component.get("v.userIterated");
      getSelectUser = JSON.stringify(getSelectUser);
         
         arrayList.push(getSelectUser)
         
       
      
      var compEvent = component.getEvent("selectUserEvent");
        
         compEvent.setParams({"selectedUser" : getSelectUser});  
      
         compEvent.fire();
          
    }, ```






<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="userIterated" type="User" />
    <aura:attribute name="listSave" type="List" />
    <!--Register the component level event-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="selectUserEvent" type="c:selectUserByEvent"/>
    
 <li role="presentation" onclick="{!c.selectUser}" class="slds-listbox__item">
    <div class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                <span class="slds-media__body">
         <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{!v.userIterated.Name}</span>
              </span>
           </div>
    </li>
</aura:component>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it it was like this

```
 var compEvent = $A.get("e.c.selectUserEvent");
```

and not

```
var compEvent = component.getEvent("selectUserEvent");
```

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the value from the attribute, you need to store it again.

```
  var arrayList = component.get('v.listSave')
  var getSelectUser = component.get("v.userIterated");
  getSelectUser = JSON.stringify(getSelectUser);
  arrayList.push(getSelectUser);
  component.set('v.listSave', arrayList);
```

Comment: tried but it replace  the old value everytime I click